# PhD advisor keeps insisting I define commonly used terms (terms of art)

Tags: phd, advisor

I work in an NLP-adjacent area and while my advisor is pretty familiar with NLP in general, she isn't super familiar with the specific sub-domain I'm working in. While editing my paper, she strongly asks me to explicitly define some utterly obvious terms that would be extremely out of place in a typical paper for this venue (think having to define what "force" is in a physics paper).

I completely realize that there are times when even seemingly obvious terms can be ambiguous, but trust me when I say that this is NOT one of those cases.

When I point this out to her (even with evidence of other papers in the field), she gets super defensive and says something to the effect of "You are effectively saying that I don't know this field. Do you realize how problematic it is?" I wish she was at least open to the idea that NLP is such a fast-paced field that there might be something she doesn't know (and honestly, even reading one or two papers in my field will clear up things for her).

This may seem like a minor thing, but arguing about defining every small term that SHE doesn't understand makes me feel VERY frustrated, because I would either like constructive feedback on the ACTUAL IDEA OR I would at least like to be left alone in confidence that I know what I'm doing. Instead, I get nit-picked.

This was a bit of a rant, but any advice would help!

Comment: Could you define NLP for us here?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think it's "utterly obvious" that the OP is talking about [neuro-linguistic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming) /s

Comment: Given the quotation marks around "utterly obvious", I assume that there is some kind of ironic joke here ... but since I assumed that neuro-linguistic programming *was* the subject being discussed,, the joke has passed me by. Enlightenment please!

Comment: @CrimsonDark: There're a few things commonly abbreviated as "_NLP_", including ["_non-linear programming_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming), ["_natural language processing_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), and ["_natural language programming_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_programming).  The joke presumably has another layer to it that we might not say.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what your specific question is.

Answer (score 12):

Communication is difficult. Jargon and acronyms can make the message difficult to understand. It is easy to assume the reader knows what do you mean, but it is the purpose of writing to communicate properly.

As an example, I was once compiling results from many papers on the same topic, but written by authors coming from different scientific communities. One of the key parameters of the study can be defined in 5 different ways. Each of these 5 ways is very logical, and convenient in various situations, but they are incompatible. Some papers didn't bother to mention which way was used, which rendered the results useless for me. Possibly those authors didn't think of the other 4 ways to define the parameter.

It is not uncommon for good papers to start by explaining context of the study before progressing to details. This demonstrates a good understanding of the topic, as well as helps the reader to follow.

> I wish she was at least open to the idea that (...) there might be something she doesn't know

Most scientists are well aware they don't know everything. This only supports the need for effective communication.

It is impossible for us to say what's going on in your papers, and between you and your advisor. However, if you are failing to explain to her what you are doing, it is not a good sign.

Answer (score 11):

> [W]hile my advisor is pretty familiar with NLP in general, she isn't
> super familiar with the specific sub-domain I'm working in.

Do you only want your paper to be comprehensible to experts in the specific subdomain (as opposed to e.g. your advisor) who are intimately familiar with the jargon of the field as of 2023 (as opposed to 2018, or 2028)? Then by all means omit the definitions. But this of course means that you are saying that your advisor (and by extension, other experts in NLP who are not experts in your specific subdomain) is not part of the intended audience of the paper and that it does not matter if she can understand the paper easily or not.

Now, if it's your paper, it's your choice. On the other hand, unless you run up against a page limit, there is no downside to putting in the effort to make your paper accessible to a broader audience. The more accessible a paper is, the more useful it is to the scientific community. Isn't that the goal? Your advisor is simply pushing you to make your paper more accessible to a larger number of people, which is certainly what you *should* want.

Note that it is, in fact, entirely possible that you do know more about a specific subdomain of NLP than your advisor does, but this is *very different* from knowing more about how to write a good paper than your advisor does. The latter skill in particular involves learning how to write papers that are easily digestible by the actual reader, rather than the imagined reader who is familiar with all the "utterly obvious" terms.

It is common for Ph.D. students who have only really focused on one specific topic and interacted with one specific scientific subcommunity to falsely imagine that the definitions and notions they are using are common knowledge. In reality, scientists even from the neighboring subdiscipline might not be familiar with what you consider to be the most basic results and definitions from your subdiscipline.

Finally (assuming that you are correctly relaying what your advisor said), trying to browbeat you by claiming that you are doing something "problematic" if you imply that there are things she does not know about your specific subdomain is, in my book at least, not great behavior. Of course, a certain amount of intellectual humility from the student is expected, but certainly there is nothing "problematic" (in the sense of "morally questionable" or "potentially offensive") in disagreeing with your supervisor's advice.

P.S.:

> and honestly, even reading one or two papers in my field will clear up things for her

Perhaps. Or perhaps the authors of those two papers decided to follow your logic too and did not bother to clarify their "utterly obvious" terminology either.

> I would either like constructive feedback on the ACTUAL IDEA

She is giving you feedback on how to best present that idea. That is part of her job as an advisor, and it is part of your job as a PhD student to learn how to present your ideas well.

Answer (score 10):

I don’t know anything about NLP, or what it even stands for, so this is more of a general point.

As a frame challenge, you should perhaps just for a moment consider that your supervisor knows better than you do about what’s an appropriate amount of detail to write in a paper. As a PhD student, you are at the beginning of your journey and there might be a lot of things that **you** don’t know and aren’t aware of. Being humble and listening to senior people is the best way to learn the unwritten rules of your field. You don’t need to bow down to authority, but you do need to have the maturity to when and who to argue with.

Take a moment to reflect on how she, as an experienced academic, might feel when a relatively inexperienced PhD student tells them that they know the right way to do things and she doesn’t. I think a lot of people would get defensive in such a situation.

My advice - just write the definitions. No harm can come from including them if they really are necessary and a lot of harm and ill feeling can come from acting like you know more than your supervisor does. Knowing which battles to fight is one of the most important skills you need to learn in academia.

Comment: +1 on "knowing which battles to fight" this is very important advice more generally too. Learning where to put effort and where to put up a fight, and to not take losses personally. You can really been yourself by fighting the wrong fight. I've burned myself many times fighting the wrong fights. I eventually learned better though!